# how to get value and set value of cck custom field

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, cck

I know it might be a silly question to ask, but I have a field say a and b, now how to get the value and set the value for a and b.
Right now my code is like this..

```
$n = node_load($node->id);
$n->title;
```

I am getting the node title, I want to know how to get and set the value for a and b please, and if i set the value of a and b will itt be saved using

node_save($n);

??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a bit which version you're using and on the particular field types you're using, but something like this:

```
// Drupal 6
$n = node_load($node->id);
$n->title = 'A title';
$n->field_my_field_a[0]['value'] = 'A value';
$n->field_my_field_b[0]['value'] = 'B value';
node_save($n);

// Drupal 7
$n = node_load($node->id);
$n->title = 'A title';
$n->field_my_field_a[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'A value';
$n->field_my_field_b[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'B value';
node_save($n);
```

In both cases the field data will be saved along with the node when you call `node_save()`.

It's worth noting that the `0` index in both cases refers to the first item in a field. If a field has multiple values you can just keep adding to the array. The `value` key might need to change depending on the type of data that the field holds (for example a filefield will hold the `fid` (file id) of the file it holds so adjust accordingly.

Also `LANGUAGE_NONE` might need to be replaced by the required language code if you're using the Drupal 7 version.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing because you never explain what a and be are. But to access a cck field generally looks like this:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$field_value = $node->field_name[0]['value'];
```

If it's a multiple select have values in offsets past zero. You can set the value using that same method:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$node->field_name[0]['value'] = $field_value;
node_save($node);
```